# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-assembly, microsoft.build

When I am trying to build my solution I am getting below error. I have tried installing it in GAC but still getting this error

**Error 2   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.**

*other Info : VS2008, .Net 3.5 , Win 7 64 bit*

Comment: Please consider the hint in error message "or one of its dependencies". It may happens that assemly references by 'Microsoft.Build' is mising for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

For such issues the easiest way is to attach to the failing process and check the original issue causing the error. Just make sure that all exceptions are catched once they're thrown (in Exceptions Dialog).

Also good thing to troobleshot such issues is Assembly Binding Log Viewer

Here is manual https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx
Here is good article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx